# Visual Studio 2022 find the next line of code to execute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I am learning a new ASP.NET MVC app that uses some approaches I am not used to / familiar with. Without having to deal with the client side scripts (because there appear to be over a thousand), I want Visual Studio to go into break mode / stop at the first line of code executed on the server.

Is there a way to do that?

For example, I click a button in the web site that run a script that shows a dialog box (I don't believe any server code has executed at this point in this series of events). Then I fill in some fields and click a button in the dialog box that I know sends data back to the server. I want the sever to stop at the first line of code it attempts to execute as a result of the button being clicked.

I thought you used to be able to put the app in Break mode, then you could use the Step Into button to take you to the next line of code but this no longer seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a small app, you can place a breakpoint in each controller action.  Any given request should generally route to an action method.  Though keep in mind there can also be middleware which gets executed before the action method.  If you've inherited something more complex then you can observe the request in the browser's debugging tools and use its URL to find the target action.  Overall it really depends on the application and the specific operation you're looking to debug.

Comment: Thanks @David - that is what we were doing - watching in the network traffic of the debugger tool.  I just thought there used to be a way to have VS stop at the next line executed.  Maybe I will add that as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to find out what code is executed on the server when you click a button in the web site. Though you need to manually configure Runtime Flow to monitor your web application as described here https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/documentation/quick_start.html

Comment: Thanks for the information @SergeyVlasov.  For now I think the network traffic will be the quickest and easiest way.  I do have another of my personal projects that uses Xamarin Forms (soon to be converted to .Net Maui.)  With the Runtime Flow track the execution of a Xamarin Forms / .Net Maui app?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr Unfortunately, Xamarin and Maui are not supported.